# Modules over the trivial ring

Tags: modules

I know that a module is the ring-theoretic analogue of a vector space. My question is, is every module over the trivial ring $\{0\}$ a singleton set? Or can there be a module over the trivial ring that has higher cardinality than $1$?

Comment: Have you checked what the axioms would say?

Comment: You must have $1x=x$ for all $x$, and therefore $x=1x=0x=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio that assumes all rings have $1$ (and that all such modules must be unital), which not everyone (including me) assumes.

Comment: I guess it comes down to the OP being more clear:  what do you require of rings, and if they must have an identity, must your modules respect that or not?

Comment: On second thought, I guess it doesn't, because the answer in the linked dupe covers all cases nicely and clearly.

Comment: @Randall Agreed and I guess my assumptions are explicit enough for a comment.